# How do I listen to icpMain events in the angular service?

Tags: javascript, angular, electron

I currently have all event listeners in main. ts
Can I transfer them all to some service, and call them from there? Let's say we leave 1 listening to the event and that it sends everything to the service itself?

in main.ts

```
    ipcMain.on('close-second', (event, data) => {
    winSecond.webContents.send('close-sec', data);
  });
    ipcMain.on('focus-on-window', () => {
    winSecond.maximize();
    focusOnMainWindow();
  });
  ipcMain.on('openDevToolsInMain', () => {
    openDevTools(winFirst);
  });

  ipcMain.on('openDevToolsInSecond', () => {
    openDevTools(winSecond);
  });
```

I want to have only 1 icpMain left in the main ts at most
I tried to make a service nearby and call from there, but I don't have enough skills and I sit with this all day, please help

Comment: If you want to write just one ipcMain event listener, you can do that. Just use one channel `message` for example. And in the listener callback you can have a `switch` statement to see what should be executed. This will require you to send extra data for each ipc request from the renderer process though to identify the action that needs to be executed